# 3d plot in python based on matrix

Tags: python, dataset, mplot3d

I have a data set created by....

```
import random

count = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(3, 6):
        for k in range(15,19):
            count.append((i, j, k, random.random()))
```

I would like to create 3d graphs of `count` vs pairs of `i`, `j`, and `k` (so 3 graphs total). I have looked through examples here: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots, but they all seem to be creating values on the fly. How do I plot the surface or mesh graphs that I want?

Comment: You can help people who are looking at the question by putting actual code that creates the dataset (or a representative dataset) in your question. It currently looks like matlab notation or similar. Ideally I would be able to paste it into my interpreter and then happily mess around with mplot3d with your data.

Comment: @MrE does that help? I am now able to use ax.tri_surf http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf  but I am getting duplicate value errors. I would like to be able plot multiple points per x,y coordinate in 3d space.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I'm just updating my matplotlib (the function is new it seems) but I'm pretty sure the answer is that you will have to do a scatter plot as you can't have a surface with multiple values per (x,y) coordinate in the same way you can't have a line with two values for one x coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got to dash but this is how I would attempt to plot your data - the `count` vs `(i,j)` example - see the index slicing on the last line or so. Happy to take a further look if you need.

```
>>> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> count = []
>>> for i in range(1, 4):
...     for j in range(3, 6):
...         for k in range(15,19):
...             count.append((i, j, k, random.random()))
...             
...         
...     
... 
>>> data = np.array(count)
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
>>> 
>>> # I think this is the sort of thing you want:
>>> 
>>> ax.plot_trisurf(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,3])
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/delaunay/triangulate.py:103: DuplicatePointWarni
ng: Input data contains duplicate x,y points; some values are ignored.
  DuplicatePointWarning,
<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection object at 0x46e8390>
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: E Thanks! I was able to play around it some more and get a scatter plot like you said. I want to work on coloring the dots a bit and stuff so I can visualize it better.